# Is there a "quick" way to visualize constrainsts on elementary classical Lagrangian Mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

The very basic ideias of Lagrangian Mechanics with some introduction to Variational Calculus isn't a great big deal to understand, I mean, aren't so difficult to understand the point of view of Lagrangian Mechanics. The point is, for me, the things begin to become struggling when *Constraints* appears in game. Again, the general picture isn't a big deal to understand; you have Lagrange's equations and you have an sub-manifold (hypersurface) defined  by an equation:

$$f(q_{1},q_{2},...,q_{k},t) = k \tag{1}$$

which is, roughly speaking, "the place where the particle is constrained to move".
Now, the book $[1]$ gives a good general picture of constrains, $[1]$ gives some examples:

$1)$ An object forced to slide along a wire: $x^{2}+y^{2} = \ell ^{2}$

$2)$ An object moving under the influence of gravity in the region outside of some sphere of radius $R$: $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} \geq R ^{2}$

So, my doubt is how can I visualize quickly an constraint? I mean following the logic a constraint is just a defined set like $1)$ or $2)$, so to identify a constraint (or to propose one) is just a matter to define a set. But when I get a problem to solve this process to realize the constraint is quite difficult to see.

$$* * *$$

$[1]$ SCHWICHTENBERG.J. *No-Nonsense Classical Mechanics: A Student-Friendly Introduction*. No-Nonsense Books. 2019.

Comment: Perhaps an example of a problem in which you do not find it straightforward to write down the constraint(s)?

Comment: The only quick way I can think of is by having a good idea of what the situation is, and having a basic knowledge of analytical geometry.